# Form validation using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create form using html CSS and JavaScript, I am tired of this now I mange to create an alert when input field is empty but it gives alert even after I add something in input field I don't know how to deal with this, also how can I check if input is string or number I want to give alert if they add number in name field any help please...….

```js
const firstname = document.getElementById("#firstname", giveAlert);

function giveAlert() {
  console.log(firstname)
  if (firstname == null) {
    alert("alert")
  } else {
    return alert(firstname)
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Main container -->

<div class="container">
  <!-- Heading -->
  <h1>Register Form</h1>

  <!-- Form -->
  <form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return false">
    <!-- Name -->
    <div class="firstname">
      <label>Firstname</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstname" />
    </div>
    <div class="middlename">
      <label>Middlename</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="lastname">
      <label>Lastname</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <!-- Gender -->
    <div class="gender">
      <label>Gender</label>
      <div class="gendertype">
        <label>Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="male" checked />
        <label>Female</label>
        <input type="radio" name="female" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Hobby -->
    <div class="hobby">
      <label>Hobby</label>
      <div class="hobbytype">
        <label>Reading</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="reading" />
        <label>Singing</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="singing" />
        <label>Dancing</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dancing" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Addres -->
    <div class="address">
      <label>Address</label>
      <textarea name="" id="" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- City -->
    <div class="city">
      <label>City</label>
      <select name="" id="">
        <option value="">Amreli</option>
        <option value="">Surat</option>
        <option value="">Rajkot</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="button">
      <button type="button" onclick="return giveAlert()">Submit</button>
      <button>Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just use the `required` property in your HTML?

Comment: you should check for for the value inside the  input tag example. document.getElementByid("firstname").value;  use this link for reference https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: OR use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): `const firstname = document.querySelector("#firstname");`

Comment: The [MDN guide on Client-side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) will be very helpful to refer to.

Comment: You have a bit of wishful thinking. [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) has only one parameter and that is the ID without the hash . Perhaps you were thinking of addEventListener `document.getElementById("firstname").addEventListener("change" giveAlert);`
`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I can not use required attribute i am creating demo of validation specifically sing JavaScript only.

Comment: @mplungjan using event listener gives me an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

Comment: Why not debug your code? Start by checking what `firstname`  contains

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your element selector, you are doing
`document.getElementById("#firstname")`

But you don't need the `#` when already querying for an ID, you would use that if you were doing `document.querySelector("#firstname")`.

So basically, you could do this:

```js
document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", giveAlert);

function giveAlert(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const firstnameval = document.getElementById('firstname').value
  alert(firstnameval || 'alert')
}
```

```html
<form id='myform'>
  <div class="firstname">
    <label>Firstname</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe the simplest of code before the optional chaining? Anyway, we like to close this as a typo-type question not really worth answering. Also I do not recommend inline event handlers and you do not return false from it, so why return giveAlert() ?

Comment: That was an edit made by someone else, I only did the part where I select the element and do the alert, as I said, you don't really need optional chaining, I just did it to reduce ifelse, and I agree with you, adding an `eventListener` is indeed the best way.

Comment: I tried this solution i am getting alert when input field is empty but i am also getting same alert when i type something in input field.......

Comment: Weird, could you upload your simplified code in a codepen, so I can see how it's being implemented?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you have the field outside the validation and you use invalid JS to handle the field value

Here is a canonical way to make a custom validation

Note I use required on the main fields and add a specific check for the hobbies

No inline event handling

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit, remove if you want to submit
    // here we will not even arrive if the required fields are empty or not selected
    const hobbies = [...document.querySelectorAll(".hobbytype [type=checkbox]:checked")]
      .map(chk => chk.value); // get all checked values
    if (hobbies.length === 0) {
      if (confirm("Wow you are boring\nMaybe check one anyway?")) {
        e.preventDefault(); // only interesting if the cancel submit has been removed
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Main container -->

<div class="container">
  <!-- Heading -->
  <h1>Register Form</h1>

  <!-- Form -->
  <form action="" id="myForm">
    <!-- Name -->
    <div class="firstname">
      <label>Firstname</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="middlename">
      <label>Middlename</label>
      <input type="text" name="middlename"/>
    </div>
    <div class=" lastname ">
      <label>Lastname</label>
      <input type="text " name="lastname"/>
    </div>
    <!-- Gender -->
    <div class="gender ">
      <label>Gender</label>
      <div class="gendertype">
        <label>Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
        <label>Female</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
        <label>Other</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Hobby -->
    <div class="hobby">
      <label>Hobby</label>
      <div class="hobbytype">
        <label>Reading</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="reading" />
        <label>Singing</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="singing" />
        <label>Dancing</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="dancing" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Addres -->
    <div class="address">
      <label>Address</label><br/>
      <textarea name="address" cols="50 " rows="5" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- City -->
    <div class="city">
      <label>City</label>
      <select name="city" required>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="Amreli">Amreli</option>
        <option value="Surat">Surat</option>
        <option value="Rajkot">Rajkot</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="button">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <button>Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```